# matplotlib Bar Chart not Appearing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying out matplotlib on Python 3 and I am encountering this weird issue with the Bar Chart bar not showing up. The codes are as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []
x.append("hello")
y.append("4")

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.title('Top Word\n')
plt.xlabel('Word')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

I've looked around trying to solve this and I've tried plt.bar(x, y, width =20) and it still doesn't seem to be working.

This is the graph that it plots:
[Plotted Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTgr4.png)

Is there anyway to get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the value of `y` to be an integer, this is why the height of the bar itself isn't defined properly.

if you'll change the piece of code to:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = 4
x.append("hello")

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.title('Top Word\n')
plt.xlabel('Word')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

you'll get the following image:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The bar is not showing because the y value isn't an integer.
Try to change it like this :

```
x.append("hello")
y.append(4)
```

I hope it could help you, thanks!